# Verify password encrypted in php by C# application

Tags: c#, php, wpf, encryption, bcrypt

On my website there is a page where clients can store a password for use in applications they buy (usually one password for all apps for their convinience). Password is hashed with bcrypt using PHP code:

```
if ( $app_pass != '' ){
  $mysalt= mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
  $options = [ 'cost' => 10, 'salt' => $mysalt,];
  $app_pass = password_hash( $app_pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options );
}
```

- where `$app_pass` in `if` statement is plain text
- later becomes bcrypted hash
- and that hash is then stored in MySQL database

When clients start bought application on his PC, enters login and password, application connects to MySQL database, retrieves hashFromDb and try to verify entered password with `BCryptHelper` class:

```
BCryptHelper.CheckPassword(passwordbox.Password, hashFromDb)
```

Yet it returns error code:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in DevOne.Security.Cryptography.BCrypt.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid salt revision

Is it the right approach to verify user entered password in WPF application against PHP encrypted password hash?

Comment: Please don't define the salt. Let `password_hash()` generate it for you. This parameter was deprecated in PHP 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`BCrypt` source code](http://derekslager.com/blog/attachment.ashx/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono/BCrypt.cs), the `System.ArgumentException` is thrown by this logic:

```
  if (salt[1] != '$') {
        minor = salt[2];
        if (minor != 'a' || salt[3] != '$') {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid salt revision");
        }
```

It appears, therefore, that the exception is thrown because the hash is not of a format that `BCrypt` supports.

[From the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), `password_hash` with the  `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` argument returns a hash that starts with `$2y$`, while the `BCrypt` implementation used by `C#` expects one that starts with `$2a$`.

I would recommend using a different method to generate the hash.

EDIT: [this Github thread](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/issues/49) has some good info on why this is happening

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies a lot. Following Github thread from your edit, I've changed in `password_hash` in my C# application `$2y$` to `$2a$` and it gave TRUE.
So to avoid hard coding hash prefix replacement in C#, I should be setting and verifying `password_hash` on either server side or client machine only, right?

Comment: Ideally, you would want to generate the hash on the client side, and verify it only on the server side.

Comment: If you have registration on both client and webui, PHP and C# would generate different BCrypt hashes. in C#, just replace $2y$ with $2a$ and the hashes should verify. Or the other way around for sending the password and verifying.

Comment: @KalebKlein Yes, I can see that replacing prefix works, but is it the proper way?

Comment: It is at least a working way. The `PHP` implementation generates hashes with a different prefix because an earlier version (which used the `$2a$` prefix) had a bug; once the bug was fixed, they changed the prefix to distinguish between good and buggy hashes. The backend (the `C#` implementation) never had this bug, however, so it still looks for hashes with the `$2a$` prefix. But a fixed (`$2y$`) `PHP` hash is exactly the same as a normal (`$2a$`) `C#` hash, so replacing the prefix will fix the compatibility issue.

Comment: One thing I would do though is one you send the password over, don't send it back. Use authentication tokens. You can make that transfer a little more secure by tying each token to an IP address. This way you're not sending passwords over the network.